# Why is the callback function not working?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

```js
let fn_one = () => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("This is shashank");
  }, 5000)

}
let fn_two = (name, callback) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Hi!, " + name);
    callback();
  }, 1000)
}

fn_two("there", fn_one)
```

Here, `fn_two` is called and it executes after one second, however, it has a callback function which is set to `fn_one()`. So it should call the callback function immediately after it executes the `fn_two` function, right? Why is it taking 5 seconds after the `fn_two` is called? Why is it not working in background?

Can anyone explain to me why the function `fn_one` is taking 5 seconds even though I have called it as a callback function?

Comment: Because `fn_one` schedules the `console.log()` after 5 second using `setTimeout(..., 5000)`?

Comment: fn_one does get called by `callback()` straight away. If you put `console.log('fn_one called');` before the setTimeout in fn_one, you should see this.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the fn_one function there is a setTimeout of 5 seconds, regardless of where you call this function, inside it has a setTimeout function, it will only execute the code inside the setTimeout after the total time is reached.

To have a function with immediate return, you need to remove setTimeout:

```js
let fn_one = () => {
  // setTimeout removed, it will run as soon as it is called.
  console.log("This is shashank");
}
let fn_two = (name, callback) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Hi!, " + name);
    callback();
  }, 1000)
}

fn_two("there", fn_one)
```

Comment: Then what is the use of callback function?, why is it not running in background?

Comment: Maybe you're confusing some things, read about callback functions [here](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-callback/).